# get the value of an object key value that was stringify

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I save some items in localstorage and stringify the key value before storing it.

```
localStorage.setItem(this.set_name, JSON.stringify(this.description))
```

That gives me key:

```
item1 Value: [{"description": "some description that was store"}, {"description": "some description that was store"}]
```

When i get the key value with `JSON.parse` it returns as an Object Object as expected, So without doing the `JSON.parse` it will return the whole value as is.

What I want to do is to return what's inside the description only, the "some description that was store" and not the whole value.

How would I do it?

```
function loadStorage() {
    $itemSection = $("#item-section-set");
    var keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
        i = 0,
        key;
    for (; key = keys[i]; i++) {
        let itemDesc = localStorage.getItem(key);
         console.log(JSON.parse(itemDesc))
    }
}
```

Console gives me `'(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]'`

Comment: May you give a clearer example of what you want, and what you're currently getting?

Comment: Where do you use your `JSON.parse` in your code?

Comment: Would it not be easier to just save `["some description that was store", "some description that was store"]`

Comment: ```function loadStorage() {
    $itemSection = $("#item-section-set");
    var keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
        i = 0,
        key;
    for (; key = keys[i]; i++) {
        let itemDesc = localStorage.getItem(key);
         console.log(JSON.parse(itemDesc.join(";"))
    }
}``` try to add join(';'). itemDesc is array, join will convert it into string

Comment: You question is very unclear,   you can save multiple items in localStorage so what is unclear to me? is that if ver say single value, what is your single, value? [{..},{...}] or {}, if you write what you are doing exact code then i might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse it first, and then fetch it from the array.

Considering that `var stringy` is the data you got from your localstorage, replace it with `localStorage.getItem(<your key>);`

```js
var stringy = "[{\"description\": \"some description that was store 1\"}, {\"description\": \"some description that was store 2\"}]"

var parsedArray = JSON.parse(stringy);

for(var i = 0; i  < parsedArray.length; i++){
    document.getElementById('area').innerHTML += '<p>'+parsedArray[i].description+'</p>';
}
```

```html
<div id="area"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general i would create separate service like
storage it should make stringify on save and JSON.parse on get
also it should have inner cache object - parsed object or undefined if object is not in cache and should be extracted and parsed from localStorage

if you are aware about performance, and you can't use JSON.parse due to too large object or similar, i would try to save descriptions in separate key-value pair
like

`localStorage.setItem(this.set_name, JSON.stringify(this.description));
localStorage.setItem(this.set_name+'_'+this.descriptionKey,JSON.stringify(this.description))`

to have possibility to retrieve description only by descriptionKey without parsing all object

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand you problem, but m not sure if i did, still assuming, you are saving whole List/Array as an one item in single LocalStorageItem, you will have multiple descriptions in one item, so there are multiple arrays, and each array having multiple objects hence multiple descriptions, heres my solution for this problem, if you explain more i will edit the same.

```
function loadStorage() {
    $itemSection = $("#item-section-set");
    var keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
    i = 0,
    key;
    for (; key = keys[i]; i++) {
        let itemDesc = localStorage.getItem(key);
         var oneLocalStorageItem = JSON.parse(itemDesc);
         oneLocalStorageItem.map(function(oneObjectItem){
             console.log(oneObjectItem.description);
         })
    }
}
```